# What is the meaning of Visual Studio Installed products version numbers?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

In the "About" box for Visual Studio 2008 and 2010, there is a list of "Installed products". "Products" other than updates, e.g. "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010", have some kind of version number after them.

What is the exact meaning of this number? Do the different components of the number have specific meanings?

I just set up a second dev computer with VS 2008 and VS 2010. The same KBxxx updates are installed on the new system and my current system. However, the numbers after the installed products differ. The first two parts of the number match, but the last two parts differ. What does it mean that they are different, and if that's important, how do I get the installs to be identical?

Comment: Do you mean the code which windows software identifies which software it is(2008 and 2010)? You can easily identify them by opening the file in txt format

Comment: No he's talking about some LICENSE number besides the Installed product...seems pointless.

Answer (score 2):

These numbers are not version numbers but "product ID" numbers. They can be found in different subkeys of

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\XXXX\Registration

They apparently are only significant for licensing and registration, and indicate nothing about the actual software.